# MATLAB neural network weight and bias initializaiton

Tags: matlab, initialization, neural-network

I'm creating a neural network in one part of my program and using it's weights and biases for another neural network in other part so I have the following code:

```
net_b = patternnet(10);
net_b = configure(net,INPUT,Target);
Weights = getwb(net);
```

I will use this neural network weights and biases for creating another neural network as below:

```
 net = patternnet(10);
 net = configure(net,INPUT,Target);
 net = setwb(net,Weights);
```

Everything was good until this stage, but then I wanted to disable pre-processing from the neural network (because I did it in a stage of the program before inserting the data to the neural network), so I used these functions:

```
net.inputs{1}.processFcns={};
net.outputs{2}.processFcns={};
```

When I used the above two functions and checked the weights in the input layer or biases in the output layer, everything is removed and I have an empty matrix, but in the hidden layer everything is normal. How can I do these without removing my weights and biases?